# How does the MarketingCloud Send API Work? Can I do this with node.js?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, node.js

Can I use the SOAP send API using node.js & [fuelSDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/index-sdk.htm)?

This process used to be documented in the [SOAP API section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm). It has recently disappeared from this page. Is this now no longer possible?

If necessary, I could post our partial code, but I am more concerned if this is possible using fuel-node, than if my code is working correctly.

Thanks for the info.

[image: Can I do this using node.js ?]
[image: This process used to be documented, is it no longer possible?]

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure You can do it. 
But node.js won't be enough. 
You need a email service like SMTP or IMAP.
And a Data Base. And might be other tools, depending on how You expect the tool works. 
Marketing Cloud is not really modern. Actually I think You should review something newer.

Actually there are other platforms already working in a similar way.

Check for example, www.mailjet.com . They use the Google Cloud Engine to support theirs platform.